# c# error regarding polymorphism.at the end of the program with Get String() method it says that there is no any method like obj.earnings()

Tags: c#, polymorphism

```cs
namespace OOPHomework
{
    public partial class EmployeeTestForm : Form
    {
        public EmployeeTestForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //Construct objects of different types
            Boss boss = new Boss("John", "Smith", 800);

            CommissionWorker commissionWorker =
               new CommissionWorker("Sue", "Jones", 400, 3, 150);

            PieceWorker pieceWorker = new PieceWorker("Bob", "Lewis",
               Convert.ToDecimal(2.5), 200);

            HourlyWorker hourlyWorker = new HourlyWorker("Karen",
               "Price", Convert.ToDecimal(13.75), 50);


            //Declare a reference and use it to process boss object
            Employee employee = boss;
            string output = GetString(employee) + boss + " earned " +
                  boss.Earnings().ToString("C") + "\n\n";

            //Use reference  to process commission Worker object
            employee = commissionWorker;
            output += GetString(employee) + commissionWorker +
               " earned " +
               commissionWorker.Earnings().ToString("C") + "\n\n";

            //Use reference  to process pieceWorker object
            employee = pieceWorker;
            output += GetString(employee) + pieceWorker +
               " earned " + pieceWorker.Earnings().ToString("C") +
               "\n\n";

            //Use reference  to process hourlyWorker object
            employee = hourlyWorker;
            output += GetString(employee) + hourlyWorker +
               " earned " + hourlyWorker.Earnings().ToString("C") +
               "\n\n";

            displayLabel.Text = output;
        }

        // return string that contains Employee information
        public static string GetString(object emp)
        {
            return emp.ToString() + " earned " + ***emp.Earnings()***.ToString("C")   + "\n";
        }
    }
}`
```

Here it says that there is no any method like `emp.Earnings()`. However, in my code there is a separate function for earnings with each class.

Comment: You are passing in an object, and objects dont have such method. I dont know your Employee class, but I guess it is the base class which has Earnings declared, so maybe use that?

Answer (score 0):

> Here it says that there is no any method like emp.Earnings().but in my code there is a separate function for earnings with each class.

```
public static string GetString(object emp)
```

The object passed as `object emp` actually has a method `emp.Earnings()` *as an Employee*
but not *as an object*. The methods, properties, etc. your object has are determined by **how you treat that object**. In this case, you want to treat your `object emp` **as an Employee**, in order to do that you need to use a [cast expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast#cast-expression).

```
// return string that contains Employee information
public static string GetString(object obj)
{
    Employee emp = obj as Employee;
    if (emp != null) 
        return emp.ToString() + " earned " + emp.Earnings().ToString() + "\n";
    else return "Object is not an employee!";
}
```